# How to unit-test decorated functions?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I tried lately to train myself a lot in unit-testing best practices. Most of it makes perfect sense, but there is something that is often overlooked and/or badly explained: how should one unit-test decorated functions ?

Let's assume I have this code:

```
def stringify(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        return str(func(*args))

    return wrapper


class A(object):
    @stringify
    def add_numbers(self, a, b):
        """
        Returns the sum of `a` and `b` as a string.
        """
        return a + b
```

I can obviously write the following tests:

```
def test_stringify():
    @stringify
    def func(x):
        return x

    assert func(42) == "42"

def test_A_add_numbers():
    instance = MagicMock(spec=A)
    result = A.add_numbers.__wrapped__(instance, 3, 7)
    assert result == 10
```

This gives me 100% coverage: I know that any function that gets decorated with `stringify()` gets his result as a string, and I know that the undecorated `A.add_numbers()` function returns the sum of its arguments. So by transitivity, the decorated version of `A.add_numbers()` must return the sum of its argument, as a string. All seems good !

However I'm not entirely satisfied with this: my tests, as I wrote them could still pass if I were to use another decorator (that does something else, say multiply the result by 2 instead of casting to a `str`). My function `A.add_numbers` would not be correct anymore yet the tests would still pass. Not awesome.

I could test the decorated version of `A.add_numbers()` but then I would overtest things since my decorator is already unit-tested.

It feels like I'm missing something here. What is a good strategy to unit-test decorated functions ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up splitting my decorators in two. So instead of having:

```
def stringify(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        return str(func(*args))

    return wrapper
```

I have:

```
def to_string(value):
    return str(value)

def stringify(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        return to_string(func(*args))

    return wrapper
```

Which allows me later to simply mock-out `to_string` when testing the decorated function.

Obviously in this simple example case it might seem overkill, but when used over a decorator that actually does something complex or expensive (like opening a connection to a DB, or whatever), being able to mock it out is a very nice thing.

Comment: I think this is the best way to go. In my case I'm testing a decorated function that has injected parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Test the *public interface* of your code.  If you only expect people to call the decorated functions, then that's what you should test.  If the decorator is also public, then test that too (like you did with `test_stringify()`).  Don't test the wrapped versions unless people are directly calling them.

Comment: I believe you read my question a bit too fast. I do not intend to write functional tests but unit-tests.

Comment: The fact that `add_numbers` is really another function decorated by `stringify` is an implementation detail. Test that `add_numbers` works as intended, and it won't matter if you use a different decorator (or no decorator at all).

Comment: @chepner: Unit-tests are precisely here to test implementation details. Again, if we were talking about functional/integration tests I would agree. That's just off-topic here.

Comment: @ereOn: [unit testing of private methods](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UnitTestingNonPublicMemberFunctions) is controversial at best.  You don't want to test implementation details, because they could change at any time.  All you (should) care about is whether the software *works*, and that's best determined by testing the public interface of each unit (hence "unit testing").

Comment: @Kevin: As a developer of my library, everything is public to me. I definitely want to test everything, especially the implementation. If for some reason the implementation needs to change, I'm more than willing to pay the price and get rid of/rewrite the no-longer matching tests. There shouldn't be too many tests to change if I'm not over-testing in the first place (which is the exact reason why I'm asking this question).

Comment: @ereOn: "I'm more than willing to pay the price and get rid of/rewrite the no-longer matching tests" - **that** is the epitome of overtesting.  If you need to rewrite a *significant* number of tests for a non-breaking change, you are testing too much.

Comment: @Kevin You misinterpreted what I said. My point is basically that I shouldn't have to change more tests than the amount of code I change. Small code changes = small unit test changes. Again, there is clearly some confusion between **unit** tests and **integration** tests. The latter makes sure that the observable behavior won't change no matter the implementation. The first makes sure that my implementation details operator, at a unit level, exactly how they are supposed to.

I have both tests types in my code base but **in this question, I'm only interested in unit tests.**

Comment: @ereOn: I think you may be confused.  Unit tests test the public interface of a unit.  Integration tests test the interactions of multiple units.  I'm not aware of any testing discipline which specifically encourages testing implementation details.  Such details shouldn't be tested because they need the freedom to change.

Comment: @Kevin: "Unit tests test the public interface of a unit." Exactly. Now the thing is, for a class method, the private attributes of the class are public in regards to the method. They are no different than the attributes of the function or its return value. This is even more observable in Python where the `self` argument itself is explicit. The expression "implementation detail" has a different meaning depending on the evaluation context: when looking from the outside, my private argument is an implementation detail, but from within the function, not at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78226/discussion-between-kevin-and-ereon).

Comment: @Kevin May given a function gets decorated arbitrarily, how do you propose testing the original function?  Ex.  `add()` is decoratored with `@floatify` or `@stringify` or both, how do you test `add()`?

Comment: @pylang: From the perspective of your module's public interface, there *is* no original function.  You should not test things that don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

One of the major benefits of unit testing is to allow refactoring with some degree of confidence that the refactored code continues to work the same as it did previously. Suppose you had started with

```
def add_numbers(a, b):
    return str(a + b)

def mult_numbers(a, b):
    return str(a * b)
```

You would have some tests like

```
def test_add_numbers():
    assert add_numbers(3, 5) == "8"

def test_mult_numbers():
    assert mult_numbers(3, 5) == "15"
```

Now, you decide to refactor the common parts of each function (wrapping the output in a string), using your `stringify` decorator.

```
def stringify(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        return str(func(*args))

    return wrapper

@stringify
def add_numbers(a, b):
    return a + b

@stringify
def mult_numbers(a, b):
    return a * b
```

You'll notice that your original tests continue to work after this refactoring. It doesn't matter *how* you implemented `add_numbers` and `mult_numbers`; what matters is they continue to work as defined: returing a stringified result of the desired operation.

The only remaining test you *need* to write is one to verify that `stringify` does what *it* is intended to do: return the result of the decorated function as a string, which your `test_stringify` does.

---

Your issue seems to be that you want to treat the unwrapped function, the decorator, *and* the wrapped function as units. But if that's the case, then you are missing one unit test: the one that actually runs `add_wrapper` and tests its output, rather than just `add_wrapper.__wrapped__`. It doesn't really matter if you consider testing the wrapped function as a unit test or an integration test, but whatever you call it, you need to write it, because as you pointed out, it's not sufficient to test just the unwrapped function and the decorator separately.

Comment: I'm afraid I chose an example that was too simple. My concern is that if `stringify()` is somehow incorrect (say I mistyped `srt` instead of `str`), now all the tests of my decorated functions fail, but they should not: their implementation **is** correct, yet their tests fail. That is not acceptable as it defeats the whole point of having unit tests.

Comment: @ereOn: Then write a separate test for `stringify()`.  That will fail too, and then you'll know it was the decorator that broke.

Comment: @Kevin: Having several unrelated tests that fail for a one-line change is clearly a sign that one is over-testing in the first place. In this very simple example it will be obvious what broke. In a much more complex one, not so much.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that it's not your tests that are broken, but your test *runner*. Don't run tests that depend on `stringify` working if the test(s) for `stringify` fail.

Comment: @chepner: Unfortunately, I can't find a simple way to do that in pyunittest.  The `@skipIf` decorator seems designed for things which can be determined statically at import time.

Comment: @ereOn One simple option to write flexible tests might be to cast the results to the most general type.  For example `assert str(float(add_numbers(3, 5))) == "8.0"` should work whether you `@stringify`, `@floatify` or leave the function undecorated.

Comment: how to test, if the function was wrap by decorator, i afraid I change it in future by mistake